# How to use group_by and summarise over several subsets from same data.frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

I got the following data.frame:

```
     country1 value1 country2 value2 country3 value3
2375    Other     43   Jordan     30       NA     NA
2366    Other     89   Turkey     29       NA     NA
4904   Turkey     50     Iraq     28       NA     NA
4786   Jordan     20   Turkey     25       NA     NA
5816   Jordan      7   Turkey     10       NA     NA
2365  Lebanon     18    Other      9       NA     NA
```

where value1, value2 and value3 are independent of each other.

I want basically to obtain a table summarising each country and its aggregated value:

```
  country total_value
1    Iraq         294
2  Jordan         993
3 Lebanon        1632
4   Other         167
5  Turkey         942
```

I have tried a 'brute' approach by separately subsetting three times the original data.frame, binding the resulting subsets and then grouping and summarising using dplyr:

```
subset1 <- my_data %>% select(country = country1, value= value1)

subset2 <- my_data %>% select(country = country2, value = value2)

subset3 <- my_data %>% select(country = country3, value = value3)

subset_all <- bind_rows(subset1, subset2, subset3)

my_result <- subset_all %>% group_by(country) %>% summarise(total_value = sum(value, na.rm=TRUE))
```

I would like to obtain the same result in a more 'elegant' way. I have tried approaches using either 'gather' from dplyr or 'melt' from data.table, but for some reason I get slightly higher figures (I guess some rows are being duplicated). Any suggestion on how to improve this code?). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more dynamic way to obtain your subsets, **ASSUMING THAT YOU WANT TO SPLIT EVERY 2 COLUMNS**, i.e.

```
df <- unname(df)

do.call(rbind, split.default(df, rep(seq(ncol(df)/2), each = 2))) %>% 
   group_by(country) %>% 
   summarise(res = sum(value)) %>% 
   filter(!is.na(country))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 2
>   country   res
>   <fct>   <int>
> 1 Jordan     57
> 2 Lebanon    18
> 3 Other     141
> 4 Turkey    114
> 5 Iraq       28
> ```

Comment: Thanks! this looks like the way I was looking for, but I get an "Error in if (facCol[jj]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". I just added "names(df) <- rep(c("country","value"),3)" after your "unname' call and now works!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
result <- data.frame(
  country = as.vector(t(keep(df, str_detect(names(df),  "country")))),
  value = as.numeric(as.vector(t(keep(df, str_detect(names(df),  "value")))))
) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarise(res = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))

result

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  country   res
  <fct>   <dbl>
1 Iraq       28
2 Jordan     57
3 Lebanon    18
4 Other     141
5 Turkey    114
```

1. Detect the names which contain "country" or "value".
2. USe the function `keep` from the `purrr` package to only keep the columns which are `TRUE` for that conditions.
3. Create a vector and create a new dataframe
4. Get rid of na values
5. `group_by` and `summarise` as you want.

I think the `str_detect` and `keep` functions are a nice way, since they provide flexibility if your dataframe is labelled correctly.